# How to customise ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am trying  to put specific ticks but in that process the minor ticks are not showing anymore. How to show the minor ticks as well.
Here is an example:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, x}, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

[image]

In the x-axis I want to put ticks 1,2,3,4...,10. So I do

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, x}, {x, 0, 10}],Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, All}]
```

[image]

But now I destroyed all the minor ticks on the x-axis. Is there any way to bring them back?
Thanks.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Comment: thank you for reminder. I was actually hoping for some easy and elegant solution and thus was waiting for a bit. I thought this question is going to be duplicate because  many must have experienced this issue. To me however both these solutions are perfectly good and both does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function to add custom ticks to the ticks generated automatically (actually, to the ticks that are *close* to the automatically generated ones):

```
ClearAll[addTicks]
addTicks[axis_ : 1] :=  Module[{newticks = #, 
   autoticks =  Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}][## & @@ PlotRange[#2][[axis]]]},
     DeleteDuplicatesBy[First][Join[Transpose[{(1.) newticks, newticks}] , autoticks]]]&;
```

**Examples:**

```
llp = ListLinePlot[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10}] , ImageSize -> 300];
 
Row[{llp, Show[llp, Ticks -> {addTicks[][Range[10], llp], 
     addTicks[2][Range[0, 100, 10], llp]}]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
lp3d = ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 50, 10}], 
   DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 50}} , ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{lp3d, Show[lp3d, Ticks -> {addTicks[][Range[0, 10, 2], lp3d], 
     addTicks[2][Range[0, 50, 10], lp3d]}] }, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a kludge, but it works:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, x}, {x, 0, 10}], 
    Ticks -> {Union[Table[{i, i, {.01, 0}}, {i, 10}], 
                    Table[{j/4, " ", {.005, 0}}, {j, 40}]], All}]
```

or

```
Ticks -> {Table[
   If[Mod[i, 4] == 0, {i/4, i/4, {.01, 0}}, 
                      {i/4, " ", {.005, 0}}], 
      {i, 40}], All}
```